Julia - AssertionError in K-medoids algorithm
I am using K-medoids to reduce my data (potential future scenarios of a stock's price) from 400 scenarios to n = 25.
I computed the distance amtrix based on the Eucledian distance:
C = pairwise(Euclidean(), data', data')

where data are my 400 scenarios - the data file can be found at link. Then I run K-medoids:
kmedoids(C, n, init = :kmpp)

I get the error:
ERROR: AssertionError: !(isempty(grp))

Does any of you know what could be wrong? It seems to run fine in Python (from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids), but I guess the two K-medoids functions are different.
I haven't been able to find any documentation on why it fails..

(Example)
(In general, please provide minimal complete workable example code demonstrating the problem so readers can quickly reproduce it by importing the same packages and reading into the same data object.  I guessed the following.)
import Clustering.kmedoids
import Distances.Euclidean
import Distances.pairwise
import DelimitedFiles.readdlm

data = readdlm("data.csv")

(Now your code reproduces the error.)
n = 25
C = pairwise(Euclidean(), data', data')
kmedoids(C, n, init = :kmpp)

ERROR: AssertionError: !(isempty(grp))
Stacktrace:
 [1] _find_medoid(dist::Matrix{Float64}, grp::Vector{Int64})
   @ Clustering C:\Users\...\.julia\packages\Clustering\JwhfU\src\kmedoids.jl:229
 [2] _kmedoids!(medoids::Vector{Int64}, dist::Matrix{Float64}, maxiter::Int64, tol::Float64, displevel::Int64)
   @ Clustering C:\Users\...\.julia\packages\Clustering\JwhfU\src\kmedoids.jl:148
 [3] kmedoids(dist::Matrix{Float64}, k::Int64; init::Symbol, maxiter::Int64, tol::Float64, display::Symbol)
   @ Clustering C:\Users\...\.julia\packages\Clustering\JwhfU\src\kmedoids.jl:77
 [4] top-level scope
   @ REPL[13]:1

Answer
Maybe not enough distinct values in the data to create 25 or more different non-empty clusters.
Set(data)

produces
Set{Float64} with 24 elements:
  -26.917
  12.619999999999997
  12.811
  12.79
  -4.722000000000001
  -27.619000000000003
  12.771
  11.009999999999998
  12.800999999999995
  -27.649
  9.980999999999995
  12.780999999999999
  10.780000000000001
  12.820999999999998
  12.790999999999997
  -27.001
  -27.586000000000002
  10.210999999999999
  7.9809999999999945
  11.989999999999995
  -4.579000000000001
  7.9709999999999965
  9.190999999999995
  -11.868000000000002

The ?kmediods REPL help documentation ends with a note on the algorithm.

The function implements a K-means style algorithm instead of PAM (Partitioning Around Medoids). K-means style
algorithm converges in fewer iterations, but was shown to produce worse (10-20% higher total costs) results (see
e.g. Schubert & Rousseeuw (2019)).

The Clustering.kmedoids documentation references

Teitz, M.B. and Bart, P. (1968). Heuristic Methods for Estimating the Generalized Vertex Median of a Weighted Graph. Operations Research, 16(5), 955–961. doi:10.1287/opre.16.5.955
Schubert, E. and Rousseeuw, P.J. (2019). Faster k-medoids clustering: Improving the PAM, CLARA, and CLARANS Algorithms. SISAP, 171-187. doi:10.1007/978-3-030-32047-8_16


I think you are absolutely right - thanks a lot :) And thanks for your feedback on the question in general :)

You're welcome!

The underling reason is in the answer of @user9712582.
In certain situations, you would prefer to have some empty classes than a error.
In such cases, you can use BetaML.KMedoidsClusterer:

julia> using HTTP, DelimitedFiles, Pipe, BetaML, Statistics

julia> url = "https://github.com/user-attachments/files/16040190/data.csv";

julia> data = @pipe HTTP.get(url).body  |> readdlm(_);

julia> unique(data)
24-element Vector{Float64}:
  12.79
  12.790999999999997
  12.619999999999997
  12.820999999999998
 -11.868000000000002
  12.771
  12.800999999999995
 -27.619000000000003
   9.190999999999995
   9.980999999999995
 -27.649
   ⋮
 -26.917
  12.811
  -4.579000000000001
  10.780000000000001
  10.210999999999999
 -27.001
  11.989999999999995
   7.9809999999999945
  -4.722000000000001
 -27.586000000000002

julia> m = KMedoidsClusterer(n_classes=25, initialisation_strategy="grid")
KMedoidsClusterer - A K-Medoids Model (unfitted)

julia> classes = fit!(m,data)
500-element Vector{Int64}:
 25
 25
 25
 25
 25
 25
 10
 25
 10
 10
 25
  ⋮
 10
 10
 10
 25
 25
 25
  1
 10
 10
 10

julia> unique(classes)
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 25
 10
  1
 23
 24
 15

That said, 4 classes seem to be enought for your data:
pd = pairwise(data)
for i in 1:25
    m = KMedoidsClusterer(n_classes=i,initialisation_strategy="grid")
    classes = fit!(m,data)
    s = mean(silhouette(pd,classes))
    n_unique = length(unique(classes))
    println("Avg siluette for $i classes ($n_unique unique): $s")
end


Avg siluette for 1 classes (1 unique): 1.0
Avg siluette for 2 classes (2 unique): 0.9767906918585568
Avg siluette for 3 classes (3 unique): 0.99164186448072
Avg siluette for 4 classes (4 unique): 0.9929543302371584
Avg siluette for 5 classes (4 unique): 0.9929543302371584
Avg siluette for 6 classes (4 unique): 0.9929543302371584
Avg siluette for 7 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 8 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 9 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 10 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 11 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 12 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 13 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 14 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 15 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 16 classes (5 unique): 0.9858369866514152
Avg siluette for 17 classes (6 unique): 0.9872595910397074
Avg siluette for 18 classes (6 unique): 0.9872595910397074
Avg siluette for 19 classes (6 unique): 0.9872595910397074
Avg siluette for 20 classes (6 unique): 0.9872595910397074
Avg siluette for 21 classes (6 unique): 0.9872595910397074
Avg siluette for 22 classes (6 unique): 0.9872595910397074
Avg siluette for 23 classes (6 unique): 0.9861063345422215
Avg siluette for 24 classes (6 unique): 0.9861063345422215
Avg siluette for 25 classes (6 unique): 0.9861063345422215




Thanks a lot - that is actually what I wanted :)
